# Solve this PDE $xu_x+yu_y+xyu_z=0,u(x,y,0)=x^2+y^2$ (problem with general solution)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, differential, characteristics

Find the particular solution of the partia differential equation $$
xu_x+yu_y+xyu_z=0
$$
that satisfies the Cauchy condition
$$
u(x,y,0)=x^{2}+y^{2}
$$
So:
$$
\frac {dx}{x}=\frac {dy}{y} = \frac{dz}{xy}
$$
which in turn implies
$$
\begin{split}
\int \frac{dx}{x} =\int \frac{dy}{y} &\implies \ln(x)=\ln(C_1y) \\
& \implies C_1=\frac{x}{y} \vee \int \frac{dx}{x}=\int \frac{dy}{y} \\
&\implies \ln(C_1x)=y \Rightarrow C_1=\frac{y}{x}
\end{split}
$$
Now I have a problem: I could proceed by using two different approaches

1. I don't know if this is a good approach:
   $$
   \frac{dz}{xy}=\frac{dx+dy}{x+y} \implies \int dz=\int \frac{xy}{x+y} d(x+y)$$
   and what is the solution of the integral on the right side $\to$ Is it possible to integrate over $d(x+y$) on Wolfram Alpha?
   Moreover is it true that
   $$\int \frac{xy}{x+y} d(x+y) \iff \int \frac{xy}{x+y} dx + \frac{xy}{x+y} dy$$ or not?

2. Maybe this second approach works better $\to$ but I don't know if it's possible:
   $$
   \begin{split}
   \frac{dz}{xy}=\frac{dx\cdot dy}{x\cdot y} & \implies\int{dz}=\int{\left(\int{1\,dx}\right)dy} \\
   & \implies z=xy+C_2y+C_3 \\
   & \implies C_3=z-xy-C_2y
   \end{split}
   $$
   So it's a problem with two constants and Wolfram Alpha gives this general solution for the query `x*D[u[x,y,z],x]+y*D[u[x,y,z],y]+x*y*D[u[x,y,z],z]=0` $$
   \implies u(x,y,z)=F\left(\frac{y}{x},z-\frac{xy}{2}\right)
   $$
   so from Wolfram integration the result would be like $z=\frac{xy}{2}+C_{2}$

Maybe I should use approach 1, but how to calculate this integral?
 I know that
$$
\int \frac{d(x+y)}{x+y}=\ln(x+y)+\ln(C_2),
$$ but I have $xy$ in numerator $\implies \int \frac{xy}{x+y} d(x+y)$.

I think there could be even a third approach:

3. I can write
   $$
   \begin{split}
   \frac{dz}{xy}=\frac{dx}{x}+\frac{dy}{y} & \implies \int(dz)=\int(y dx)+\int(x dy) \\
   & \implies z=2xy+C_2 \\ 
   & \implies C_{2}=z-2xy
   \end{split}
   $$
   But it doesn't agree with the Wolfram Alpha solution and I don't think it's mathematically correct to do so.

Please help me.

Comment: In cylindrical coordinates the equation reduces to $$u_r+\frac{r\sin 2\theta}{2}\cdot u_z = 0$$

Comment: We use only this method on class/study (what it's in topic).

Comment: Hint: $$\frac{dz}{xy}=\frac{ydx+xdy}{2xy}=\frac{d(xy)}{2xy}$$

Comment: Ok, so $$\int(dz)=\frac{1}{2} \int d(xy) \Rightarrow z-\frac{xy}{2}=C_{2} $$ 

General Solution $$u(x,y,z)=F(\frac{y}{x},z-\frac{xy}{2})$$

Particular solution $u(x,y,0)=x^{2}+y^{2}$: $$F(\frac{y}{x},-\frac{xy}{2}) \Rightarrow x'=\frac{y}{x},y'=-\frac{xy}{2} \Rightarrow F(x',y')=(\frac{y}{x'})^{2}+(-\frac{2y'}{x})^{2}$$

So:
$$u(x,y,z)=(\frac{y}{\frac{y}{x}})^{2}+(\frac{-2*(z-\frac{xy}{2})}{x})^{2}=x^{2}+(\frac{-2z+xy}{x})^{2}$$

Comment: $u(x,y,z)=(y/x+x/y)(-2z+xy)$

Comment: where I make mistake? can you write step by step your method to get this particular solution?

Comment: To identify the function $F$, you need to have $F(x',y')$ expressed in terms of $x',y'$ alone. But $F(x',y')=(y/x')^2+(-2y'/x)^2$ still includes $x$ and $y$, so these need to be fully eliminated using $(x',y')=(y/x,-xy/2)$.

Comment: Ehh i don't know how replace "y" and "x" in your equation, when I want use my early substition $x'=\frac{y}{x} \Rightarrow y=x'x$ and $y'=-\frac{xy}{2} \Rightarrow x=-\frac{2y'}{y}$ I will get x,y regardless of whether I put it in 1 or 2 -> how to deal with this? I think that $$x'y'=\frac{y}{x} \cdot \frac{-xy}{2} = \frac{-y^{2}}{2} \Rightarrow -2x'y'=y^{2}$$ but what now with $x^{2}$?

Answer (score 4):

The method of characteristics gives the following ODEs:

\begin{eqnarray}
x'(t)&=x,\\
y'(t)&=y,\\
z'(t)&=xy,\\
u'(t)&=0
\end{eqnarray}
The first two ODEs solve to $x(t)=x_0 e^t$, $y(t)=y_0 e^t$ where $x_0=x(0),y_0(0)$. Therefore the third solves as $$z'(t)=x_0 y_0 e^{2t}\implies \frac12 x_0 y_0(e^{2t}-1)$$
where I have taken $z(0)=0$ for future convenience. The last ODE then yields $$u(x,y,z)=u(x_0,y_0,0)=x_0^2+y_0^2=e^{-2t}(x^2+y^2)$$

It remains to eliminate the $t$-dependence in favor of $x,y,z$. But from the above work we have $$z=\frac12 x_0 y_0 (e^{2t}-1)=\frac12 xy (1-e^{-2t}),$$ so $e^{-2t}=-2z/(x y)$. Hence
$$u(x,y,z)=\left(1-\frac{2z}{xy}\right)(x^2+y^2)=(x y-2z)\left(\frac xy+\frac yx\right).$$

Answer (score 3):

The Lagrange-Charpit equations for the PDE $xu_x+yu_y+xyu_z=0$ are given by
$$
\frac {dx}{x}=\frac {dy}{y} = \frac{dz}{xy}=\frac{du}{0}, \tag{1}
$$
the last expression meaning that $u=C_1$. The equation $\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{dy}{y}$ implies $y=C_2x$. Another independent equation is given by $\frac{dz}{xy}=\frac{ydx+xdy}{2xy}=\frac{d(xy)}{2xy}$, which has as solution $z=\frac{1}{2}xy+C_3$. Combining these three solutions we obtain
$$
u(x,y,z)=F(C_2,C_3)=F\left(\frac{y}{x},z-\frac{1}{2}xy\right). \tag{2}
$$
The function $F$ is determined by the condition $u(x,y,0)=x^2+y^2$, which implies
$$
F\left(\frac{y}{x},-\frac{1}{2}xy\right)=x^2+y^2. \tag{3}
$$
Let $\frac{y}{x}=t$ and $-\frac{1}{2}xy=s$; then
$$
ts=\frac{y}{x}\left(-\frac{1}{2}xy\right)=-\frac{1}{2}y^2 \implies y^2=-2ts \tag{4}
$$
and
$$
\frac{t}{s}=\frac{y}{x}\left(-\frac{2}{xy}\right)=-\frac{2}{x^2}
\implies x^2=-\frac{2s}{t}. \tag{5}
$$
Equations $(3)$-$(5)$ imply $F(t,s)=-2s\left(t+\frac{1}{t}\right).$ Combining this result with Eq. $(2)$ we finally obtain
$$
u(x,y,z)=(-2z+xy)\left(\frac{y}{x}+\frac{x}{y}\right). \tag{6}
$$

Comment: Can you explain me how we get $$\frac{dz}{xy}=\frac{ydx+xdy}{2xy}$$ How we received 2xy in denominator?

Comment: And I don't know why/how $ydx+xdy=d(xy)$, we have this equation in class $2xdx+2ydy+2zdz=0 \Rightarrow $d(x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2})=0$ and I don't know why either?

Comment: Ok product rule -> $ydx+xdy=d(xy)$, but how rule for this (what we get in class) -> $2xdx+2ydy+2zdz=0 \Rightarrow d(x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2})$ I'm more concerned about this that $dx^{2}$ means $\int dx^{2} = 2x \cdot dx$ we shouldn't write it like that $d^{2}x = 2x dx$?

Comment: So using the "identity" and after product rule for this -> $$\frac{dx}{y}=-\frac{dy}{x}=\frac{du}{2xy}$$ I can write $$\frac{du}{2xy}=\frac{xdx+ydy}{xy-xy}=\frac{xdx+ydy}{0}$$ So $xdx+ydy=0$ product rule implies $\frac{dx^{2}}{2}=\frac{d(xx)}{2}=\frac{xdx+xdx}{2}=xdx$ and similarly for $ydy$ so $$xdx+ydy=0 \Rightarrow \frac{d(x^{2}+y^{2})}{2}=0 \Rightarrow C=\frac{1}{2}(x^{2}+y^{2})$$ it is correct?